# I am building a mongoose aggregate for search mongodb documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I built an aggregate for searching according to a filter. The things that the user can search for are optional, So is there any way to make the match optional - for example the user can select a date, If he didn't select, I want the aggregate function not to use match date

```
    db.articles.aggregate(
        [ { 
            $match : { date : userSelectedDate }, { else : elseSelection} 
        } ]
    );
```

If no date is selected => cancel the date matching and match anothers

Answer (score 2):

I would try to build the query document dynamically.

```
var query = []
if (userSelectedDate){
  query.push({ $match : { date : userSelectedDate }})

db.articles.aggregate(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in mongoose documentation using: Aggregate#append(ops)

Appends new operators to this aggregate pipeline
after having the aggregate

```
    aggregate.append({ $project: { field: 1 }}, { $limit: 2 });
```

so now I can use if(condition) before appending

[mongoose documentation for append](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-append)